# Does the OpenJDK HttpURLConnection automatically decompresses requests?

Tags: gzip, httpurlconnection, java

[Note: to the best of my knowledge Android's `HttpURLConnection` does decompress the response. I'm specifically asking about the JVM. Oracle's or openJDK]

Looking at the network trace, I don't see any `accept-encoding: gzip` header. When a server returns `content-encoding: gzip`, `getInputStream()` seems to return the compressed stream instead of uncompressing it.

If there *is* support for decompressing the data, I'd appreciate a pointer to the relevant openJDK code.

Comment: AFAIK There's no out of the box decompression, you have to handle it yourself (using `GzipInputStream`) (see also http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-HttpUrlConnection-with-GZIP-encoding.html)

Comment: If the request does not indicate accept-encoding, the response shall not be encoded -- but some servers might figure that almost all browsers accept gzip, therefore they don't even check the request flag, and they don't care about http clients that don't.